# How to stop running download process by CURL?

Tags: linux, process, curl

I forgot to use > filename after curl operation.

linux console is giving contiguously garbage data(hopefully downloading and displaying the content on console).

How can we stop this process (ctrl-c s not working)?

getting continous output like this:

ÎþH2Ý¾à#qsý¼°-sáGâvâzì#éì¼ÄúÁN\t1Ã
}$ZXGcô°

executed following

```
curl http://example.com/file.tgz
```

Instead of

```
curl http://example.com/file.tgz > mongo.tgz
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to abort the currently running process – in that case, `curl` spitting out data to stdout rather than a file.

If your terminal is still showing messed up symbols, clear it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> or entering `clear`.

Comment: i tried ctrl-c but i am getting console output

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl-L` to clear the screen.

Comment: Ctrl - c killed the process, but it somhowe changed the locale to Chinese !??? Now I know what home looks like in Mandarin :)